# Rotate vector given axis

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I'm working with rotating vectors around a given axis.

The problem is stated as the following: points in space (R^3) are rotated an angle $\theta$ around an axis that goes through (0,0,0) and that's parallell to the vector (1,1,1). The rotation is in the positive direction from the tip of the vector. Determine on what point that (1,0,0) is depicted on with this transformation.

What I'm thinking is to convert the standard basis into a new basis, where one of the basis vectors are parallell to the vector (1,1,1).

If we let the x-axis in our standard basis now represent the vector (1,1,1). Now rotating through this new axis, we should be able to use the standard rotation matrix for rotation around x - axis, keeping in mind we are in our new basis.

Now, here's where I'm stuck. I know some facts about change of basis matrices. But how can I continue? Is there some easy way to visualize what needs to be done in order to solve the problem?

Thank you.